# Error (10395): VHDL Conditional Signal Assignment error at (146): conditional waveforms must have same number of elements

Tags: vhdl, variable-assignment, vga

Error (10395): VHDL Conditional Signal Assignment error at vga.vhd(146): conditional waveforms must have same number of elements.
in this line show me error

```
R<=intensity WHEN red_switch='0' AND dena='1' ELSE (OTHERS=>'1');
```

I really don't know what's wrong vhdl Altera code error but it didn't solve my problem. thanks in advance.

```
 LIBRARY ieee;
 USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
 USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
 LIBRARY lpm;
 USE lpm.lpm_components.all;
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 ENTITY vga IS
 GENERIC (
 Ha: INTEGER := 96; --Hpulse
 Hb: INTEGER := 144; --Hpulse+HBP
 Hc: INTEGER := 784; --Hpulse+HBP+Hactive
 Hd: INTEGER := 800; --Hpulse+HBP+Hactive+HFP
 Va: INTEGER := 2; --Vpulse
 Vb: INTEGER := 35; --Vpulse+VBP
 Vc: INTEGER := 515; --Vpulse+VBP+Vactive
 Vd: INTEGER := 525); --Vpulse+VBP+Vactive+VFP
 PORT (
 clk: IN STD_LOGIC; --50MHz in our board
 red_switch, green_switch, blue_switch: IN STD_LOGIC;
 pixel_clk: BUFFER STD_LOGIC;
 Hsync, Vsync: BUFFER STD_LOGIC;
 R, G, B: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
 nblanck, nsync : OUT STD_LOGIC);
 END vga;
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 ARCHITECTURE vga OF vga IS
 SIGNAL Hactive, Vactive, dena: STD_LOGIC;
 SIGNAL address: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 DOWNTO 0);
 SIGNAL intensity: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0);
 BEGIN
 -------------------------------------------------------
 --Part 1: CONTROL GENERATOR
 -------------------------------------------------------
 --Static signals for DACs:
 nblanck <= '1'; --no direct blanking
 nsync <= '0'; --no sync on green
 --Create pixel clock (50MHz->25MHz):
 PROCESS (clk)
 BEGIN
 IF (clk'EVENT AND clk='1') THEN
 pixel_clk <= NOT pixel_clk;
 END IF;
 END PROCESS;
 --Horizontal signals generation:
 PROCESS (pixel_clk)
 VARIABLE Hcount: INTEGER RANGE 0 TO Hd;
 BEGIN
 IF (pixel_clk'EVENT AND pixel_clk='1') THEN
 Hcount := Hcount + 1;
 IF (Hcount=Ha) THEN
 Hsync <= '1';
 ELSIF (Hcount=Hb) THEN
 Hactive <= '1';
 ELSIF (Hcount=Hc) THEN
 Hactive <= '0';
 ELSIF (Hcount=Hd) THEN
 Hsync <= '0';
 Hcount := 0;
 END IF;
 END IF;
  END PROCESS;
 --Vertical signals generation:
 PROCESS (Hsync)
 VARIABLE Vcount: INTEGER RANGE 0 TO Vd;
 BEGIN
 IF (Hsync'EVENT AND Hsync='0') THEN
 Vcount := Vcount + 1;
 IF (Vcount=Va) THEN
 Vsync <= '1';
 ELSIF (Vcount=Vb) THEN
 Vactive <= '1';
 ELSIF (Vcount=Vc) THEN
 Vactive <= '0';
 ELSIF (Vcount=Vd) THEN
 Vsync <= '0';
 Vcount := 0;
 END IF;
 END IF;
 END PROCESS;
 ---Display enable generation:
 dena <= Hactive AND Vactive;
 -------------------------------------------------------
 --Part 2: IMAGE GENERATOR
 -------------------------------------------------------
     PROCESS (Hsync, Vsync, Vactive, dena, red_switch,
     green_switch, blue_switch)
     VARIABLE line_counter: INTEGER RANGE 0 TO Vc;
     BEGIN
     IF (Vsync='0') THEN
     line_counter := 0;
     ELSIF (Hsync'EVENT AND Hsync='1') THEN
     IF (Vactive='1') THEN
     line_counter := line_counter + 1;
     END IF;
     END IF;
     IF (dena='1') THEN
     IF (line_counter=1) THEN
     R <= (OTHERS => '1');
     G <= (OTHERS => '0');
     B <= (OTHERS => '0');
     ELSIF (line_counter>1 AND line_counter<=3) THEN
     R <= (OTHERS => '0');
     G <= (OTHERS => '1');
      B <= (OTHERS => '0');
     ELSIF (line_counter>3 AND line_counter<=6) THEN
     R <= (OTHERS => '0');
     G <= (OTHERS => '0');
     B <= (OTHERS => '1');
     ELSE
     R <= (OTHERS => red_switch);
     G <= (OTHERS => green_switch);
     B <= (OTHERS => blue_switch);
     END IF;
    ELSE
     R <= (OTHERS => '0');
     G <= (OTHERS => '0');
     B <= (OTHERS => '0');
     END IF;
     END PROCESS;
--END vga;
 -------------------------------------------
 --ROM instantiation:
 myrom: lpm_rom
 GENERIC MAP (
 lpm_widthad => 9, --address width
 lpm_outdata => "UNREGISTERED",
 lpm_address_control => "REGISTERED",
 lpm_file => "pic_6.mif", --data file
 lpm_width => 10) --data width
 PORT MAP (
 inclock=>NOT pixel_clk, address=>address, q=>intensity);
 --Create address (row number):
 PROCESS (Vsync, Hsync)
 VARIABLE line_counter: INTEGER RANGE 0 TO Vd;
 BEGIN
 IF (Vsync='0') THEN
 line_counter := 0;
 ELSIF (Hsync'EVENT AND Hsync='1') THEN
 IF (Vactive='1') THEN
 line_counter := line_counter + 1;
 END IF;
 END IF;
 address <= conv_std_logic_vector(line_counter, 9);
 END PROCESS;
-- --Assign color values to R/G/B:
 R<=intensity WHEN red_switch='0' AND dena='1' ELSE (OTHERS=>'1');
 G<=intensity WHEN green_switch='0' AND dena='1' ELSE (OTHERS=>'1');
 B<=intensity WHEN blue_switch='0' AND dena='1' ELSE (OTHERS=>'1');
 END vga;
```

Answer (score 0):

Signal `R` is 8 bits wide:

```
R, G, B: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
```

while signal `intensity` is 10 bits wide:

```
SIGNAL intensity: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0);
```

This is not allowed in VHDL. Both must be the same width; you must either explicitly truncate `intensity` or extend `R`.

Comment: There's a requirement in VHDL there be a matching element in a waveform for each element of a composite target signal during simulation (IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.3.4 Signal update). This is also carried over to synthesis where resulting HW is required to match simulation behavior. Simulating a design prior to synthesis can oft provide more meaningful error messages.